# Hiding Iphone Keyboard on loss of focus

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

Using what I've read online people say put a button in the background of the app then when clicked that button handles closing the keyboard. However reading some other people they say resign first repsonder for the text field - does that mean the textfield has taken control of the keyboard and wont release it until specifically told to?

My .h has:

```
@interface SearchItems : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UIButton *btnKeyboard;
    IBOutlet UITextField *txtWhat;
    IBOutlet UITextField *txtWhere;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *btnKeyboard;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *txtWhat;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *txtWhere;

-(IBAction)closeKeyboard;

@end
```

The .m (cut down)

```
@synthesize btnKeyboard, txtWhat, txtWhere;

-(IBAction)closeKeyboard {

    [txtWhere resignFirstResponder];
    [txtWhat resignFirstResponder];

}
```

Which isn't working, any ideas?

Thanks

Tom

Comment: Is your IBAction definitely being called, the usual signature is `-(IBAction)doSomething:(id)sender`?

Comment: also check if your outlets are setup.

Comment: Would that bit :(id)btnKeyboard or would it literally be :(id)sender

Comment: :(id)sender would do, sender will be a pointer to the object that sent the action. If you can connect the button to the action as it stands, you will be OK, it't just that there is usually an argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the delegate methods to resignResponder:

```
 - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
 {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

Apart from this one you can also use this delegate method:

```
 - (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
 {
     [textField resignFirstResponder];
 }
```

These two methods mainly should be able to solve your keyboard hiding problem rather than using the background button technique.

Comment: Do you use these just in the .m for the file? Do you need to put anything in the .h? - Tom

Comment: You've to use these methods in .m file. Also don't forget to connect the delegate in xib where you've connected those textFields. You can also set the delegate methods using code in `-(void)viewDidLoad` method like this: `txtWhat.delegate = self;` whatever is convenient to you.